# Some help in my moment of stupidness

Tags: python, boolean, logic

so I have this project that's due and for one of the questions, after doing all the calculations, you compare two different booleans. So, if both booleans are true the answer will return false, and if both booleans are false it will return false, and it will only return true if one of the booleans are true and the other is false (doesn't matter which)

So lets say the two booleans are A and B

My code looks like this
return A != B

His code looks like this
return ((A and not B) or (B and not A))

Who is right? Are we both right?
Hes like a lot smarter than me so im just wondering if I did some stupid mistake

Comment: Please try to give an informative title to your question. As for the question: check 4 cases: A,B each true or false (2x2 combinations). You can determine these problems yourself, on paper.

Answer (score 0):

You are both right, the result is the same.
Just one option is shorter than the other or simpler.

There isn't only one way to solve a problem, as long as the result is right.
Here I offer yet another solution.

You also can use XOR  ^

```
t = False
f = False

result = t ^ f
print result
>> False

t = True
f = False

result = t ^ f
print result
>> True

t = False
f = True

result = t ^ f
print result
>> True

t = True
f = True

result = t ^ f
print result
>> False
```

Comment: First of all, answer the question - who is right, then offer an alternative. Just an alternative (with no explanation) is not going to answer or help the OP. Explain who is correct, *then* provide an alternative and at least explain what ^ is and what it does...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, both of you are right.
But I think your answer is more simple.

```
def fun(a,b):
    result = a ^ b
    #your code
    resultA= a!=b
    #your friend's code
    resultB= (a and not b) or (b and not a)

    print result
    print resultA
    print resultB
    print '-'*20

a = False
b = False
fun(a,b)

a = True
b = False
fun(a,b)

a = False
b = True
fun(a,b)

a = True
b = True
fun(a,b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
False
False
--------------------
True
True
True
--------------------
True
True
True
--------------------
False
False
False
--------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

[True False Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W405E.png)

See the above true false table.

XOR => ^

So, in this case you can use A ^ B.
However, A != B also works here.

You are both right. But, your code is more concise.